# Set a selected option in a dynamically populated select dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have a select dropdown that is dynamically populated like this:

```
var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
var minYear = year-95;
var options = [];
for(var i=minYear; i < year+1; i++){
    options.push('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
}
```

How can I set a selected option?

Comment: When i == year then select option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `selected` to the option (more info about [option selected](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)).

Your code should look like this:

```
var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
var minYear = year-95;
var options = [];
for(var i = minYear; i < year + 1; i++)
{
    if (i == year) // Condition for selected option
    {
        options.push('<option selected value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
    }
    else
    {
        options.push('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Very much appreciated. Thank you! Do you happen to know a way to focus on that selected option once the dropdown is expanded?

Comment: It should be focused.

Comment: I've added a jQuery library for styling that select dropdown which makes a ul with the options and hides the select. So  the option is not focused when expanded.

Comment: Ok. It depends on the library. But that is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    var minYear = year - 95;
    var options = [];
    for (var i = minYear; i < year + 1; i++) {

        if (i == 1950) {
            options.push('<option selected value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
        } else {
            options.push('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
        }

    }
    $("#sel").html(options);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="sel"></select>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7h8j760p/)